# Invalid query created by hibernate - spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ibm-midrange

I have a small application that uses spring boot 2.7.4 and Spring data JPA to connect to AS400. Its been working fine. Now I  am trying to upgrade it to spring boot 3 and getting this error

```
 ERROR 10876 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select * from (select s1_0.id c0,s1_0.message c1,row_number() over() rn from table1 s1_0) r_0_ where  order by r_0_.rn]] with root cause

com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0199] Keyword BY not expected. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> != >= ┬¼< ┬¼> ┬¼= IN NOT.
        at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:948) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
```

I am not sure why it is creating a second select statement(with wrong syntax) to enclose the seemingly correct select statement.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'java'
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
   implementation group: 'net.sf.jt400', name: 'jt400', version: '11.1'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   //implementation 'com.ibm.db2:jcc'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.username=**
spring.datasource.password=**
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://**
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query:values 1
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

Using JPA repository

```java
public interface Table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Table1, Long> {
    

}
```

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1")
public class Table1 {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    private String message;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

this is the call that is causing this error

```java
tablel1Repository.findAll();
```

It was working fine with spring boot 2.7.4 and with SB 3.0.0 it is not.

Comment: Try specifying hibernate dialect (`hibernate.dialect=net.sf.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect`) to ensure that Hibernate won't generate queries containing invalid SQL syntax. Reference for details - https://javabydeveloper.com/what-is-dialect-in-hibernate-and-list-of-dialects/#list-of-sql-dialects-in-hibernate

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko thanks for the suggestion.  It seems like net.sf.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect is an old/deprecated dialect. It gives me Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : net.sf.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect error. But I tried different combination of this in application.properties and still get the original 'Invalid query' error. hibernate.dialect=net.sf.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect

//spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
//spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

Comment: This bug is tracked here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15890

Comment: With spring boot 3 and DB2 I get "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error" too. The table name is put into double quotes, and that causes the error. I debugged into org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect and removed the quotes, and then the DB2-select was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s1_0.id c0,s1_0.message c1,row_number() over() rn from table1 s1_0) r_0_ where  order by r_0_.rn
```

***`where order by`***

Is not valid SQL syntax.  I don't why SB 3 would be trying that, but you might look to see if it's an open issue.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer.  Where to check for open issues?

Comment: Created an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33628

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is 100% with the version of hibernate included in SB 3. I was able to fix the problem by overriding the hibernate version in my `build.gradle` thusly:

```
ext['hibernate.version'] = '6.1.7.Final'
```