# InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException SpringDataJPA IBM AS/400 DB2 AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, db2-400

I just started a new SpringBoot/SpringDataJPA 3.0 project and I am trying to execute a `findAll()` method on a repository that extends `JpaRepository`. The entity I am using is very basic (just a few fields). I have all data configured in the application.properties file.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://valid.connection.url.here
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=VALUES 1
spring.datasource.username=omitted
spring.datasource.password=omitted
```

My server starts up fine. Everything seems good until I reach out to my endpoint which causes the following exception:

```
2023-02-23T09:25:39.803-06:00  WARN 13148 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -199, SQLState: 42601
2023-02-23T09:25:39.803-06:00 ERROR 13148 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [SQL0199] Keyword BY not expected. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> != >= �< �> �= IN NOT.
2023-02-23T09:25:39.918-06:00 ERROR 13148 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/DemoApp] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select * from (select c1_0.dc c0,c1_0.holiday_id c1,c1_0.add_date c2,c1_0.add_program c3,c1_0.add_time c4,c1_0.add_user c5,row_number() over() rn from cogleds c1_0) r_0_ where  order by r_0_.rn]] with root cause

com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0199] Keyword BY not expected. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> != >= �< �> �= IN NOT.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:948) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:745) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1821) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.<init>(AS400JDBCPreparedStatementImpl.java:357) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java:2307) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java:2084) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnectionImpl.java:2079) ~[jt400-11.1.jar:JTOpen 11.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.lambda$list$0(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:405) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy109.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.oreillyauto.java17sbtest.controller.DemoController.getCogLEDs(DemoController.java:25) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Just looking at the query Hibernate is generating it is obvious what the error is:

```
select * from 
    (select c1_0.dc c0,c1_0.holiday_id c1,c1_0.add_date c2
     ,c1_0.add_program c3,c1_0.add_time c4,c1_0.add_user c5
     ,row_number() over() rn 
    from cogleds c1_0) r_0_ 
where  -- where clause with nothing in it immediately followed by order by... 
order by r_0_.rn
```

My question is, Why?
Why is this happening? Is there a way around this?

Edit: Following up. I can 100% confirm this is a JPA/Hibernate issue because I just cobbled together a JDBC repo and ran a prepared statement and that worked fine.

CogLedJdbcRepoImpl.java

```
// imports omitted
@Repository
public class CogLedJdbcRepoImpl implements CogLedJdbcRepo {

    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public CogLedJdbcRepoImpl(@Autowired DataSource dataSource){
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<CogLed> findAll() {
        String query = "select holiday_id, dc, add_date, add_time, add_program, add_user from cogleds";
        return this.template.query(query, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CogLed.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seen this before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74894243/invalid-query-created-by-hibernate-spring-boot-3/74894766#74894766

Comment: Fixed in Spring Boot 3.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the version of hibernate included as a dependency in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. I was able to resolve the issue by overriding the version of hibernate in my `build.gradle`.

```
ext['hibernate.version'] = '6.1.7.Final'
```